# How to navigate the user from floor to floor using android application

Tags: android

I have the requirment to navigate the user from floor to floor using wifi and gps. If user have have android tablet with wifi connection and walking to get lattitude and longitude .I have to draw or voice recognition to go left or right to tell to the user.Is it possible? if it is can anybody tell how to dO?

Thanks

Comment: Like yours, I am trying to create one. Would you interested to create it together?

Answer (score 2):

First of all GPS doesn't work well/at all in closed spaces. WIFI does give you a location but its not very accurate (above 100 meters radius).

in conclusion i would say its a waste of time trying to do something like that because it will perform poorly and be pretty useless.

if you really want to go on and make it then go google for samples and examples and tutorials on how to implement the location Receiver both for FINE and COARSE location.

for the drawing part you will need the orientation sensor to tell you which way you are facing or get the bearing from the gps provider.

this is pretty general info but it should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to have people walk around and take wifi measurements at different places on each floor, then you can store this, and then you can tell where they are on that particular floor.

You may want to break the building up into grids so you can state they are in Grid 5 D for example, if that is how you label them, or at least show that on a map.

Indoors the GPS will most likely not be working.

The wifi approach isn't foolproof but if you take multiple measurements by stair entrances and elevators you should get a good idea when they change floors, and perhaps have some people able to correct the database if they know they are in a particular grid but the app tells them it is somewhere else, so you can start to get a fuzzy idea where people are.